# Какие есть рабочие объектные базы данных для .NET?

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, .net-core, oodb

Очень удобно (теоретически) использовать объектные базы данных, в сочетании с объектно ориентированными языками.

Хочется узнать есть ли такие для .NET, интересуют именно те базы которые можно использовать без оплаты. Не интересуют такие вымершие варианты как `db4o`, интересуют реально работающие и развивающиеся проекты.

Большое желание что бы было взаимодействие с EF. И в частности с веткой Core (.NET Core, EF Core).

Либо таких проектов, движков баз на данный момент нету и они не развиваются.
Если их нет, интересно было бы узнать почему. Никто не может выдержать конкуренции с MS SQL Server, SQL Lite?

Comment: Ну не всем нужно именно встраиваемое решение. А если можно отдельный сервер базы данных, то проще взять что-то типа mongodb и не писать свое. В итоге смысл разрабатывать такое (встраиваемое) решение есть только у тех, кто за деньги продает, как вот siagodb хотя бы

Comment: Развивающихся активно не заметно, db4o по моему будет лучшим вариантом для "потыкать".

Comment: @vitidev объясните пожалуйста что вы имеете ввиду под встраиваемое? что бы прямо нативно работало из программы, например с сайта?

Comment: работает в том же процессе, что и приложение. вот sqlite.так работает - нет отдельного сервера базы данных.

Comment: @Monk db4o реально классный был, я его пробовал, хорошо работал тогда, но так и не делал на нём проекты, жалко что проект закрылся

Comment: @vitidev Спасибо за информацию. Посмотрел кратко про sqlite. Возможно буду его использовать совместно с .NET Core 2.0 и EF Core. Я не фанат SQL Server, и думаю делать на чём-то более лёгком и менее проприетарном.

Comment: Новый проект планирую запускать на Linux хостинге, значит не будет SQL Server-а, как я использовал ранее. (про отдельный вариант не говорю). И вот ищу базу данных которая наиболее адекватная для этих целей с .NET Core

Comment: каждой задаче своя база данных. sqlite встраиваемая, но не просто так имеет суффикс lite. А если в остальном любую базу данных, лишь бы был адаптер. Я использую sqlite в asp.net core, но это потому что возможностей мне хватает (и в sqlite есть режим WAL). но для серьезных вещей лучше серьезные бд

Comment: @vitidev Согласен. У меня проект это сайт-движок, думаю мне и lite подойдёт. Нет планов на этот период делать high load или сотни тысяч страниц на сайте.

Comment: [SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup?view=sql-server-2017) вполне ставится и на linux

Comment: @vitidev А как делать миграции для SQLite? Почитал вот тут что там их просто не сделать https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/netcore/new-db-sqlite#changing-the-model

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин я не использую EF, так что с этим не помогу